# C++ wont print certain variables

Tags: c++

I couldn't paste the whole code in here, it's too large for the body. A full paste is here (link looks a bit untrustworthy, sorry.)

http://paste4btc.com/C4d9wg7X

However, I'm fairly certain that the error is somewhere in these blocks.

This one is a list of all items, their variables and values.

```
void itemHeartCanister()
    {
        purchasableItem1Name = "Heart Canister";
        itemHealthUpDescription = "Increases your maximum health by 1.";
        purchasableItem1Price = 25;
    }

void itemWoodenSword()
{
    purchasableItem2Name = "Wooden Sword";
    itemWoodenSwordDescription = "Increases your damage by 2.";
    purchasableItem2Price = 40;
}

void itemLeatherBoots()
{
    purchasableItem3Name = "Leather Boots";
    itemLeatherBootsDescription = "Increases your speed and defense by 1.";
    purchasableItem3Price = 30;
}

void itemGarnetNecklace()
{
    purchasableItem4Name = "Garnet Necklace";
    itemGarnetNecklaceDescription = "Increases your luck by 1.";
    purchasableItem4Price = 50;
}

void itemSpookyMemeStaff()
{
    purchasableItem5Name = "Spooky Meme Staff";
    itemSpookyMemeStaffDescription = "Fires spooky memes that do 4.20 damage each";
    purchasableItem5Price = 69;
}

void itemLeatherHelmet()
{
    purchasableItem6Name = "Leather Helmet";
    itemLeatherHelmetDescription = "A leather helmet that increases your defense by 2";
    purchasableItem6Price = 35;
}

void itemHealthPotion()
{
    purchasableItem7Name = "Health Potion";
    itemHealthPotionDescription = "A health potion that restores one health point";
    purchasableItem7Price = 20;
}

void itemManaPotion()
{
    purchasableItem8Name = "Mana Potion";
    itemManaPotionDescripton = "A potion that heals 10 mana points.";
    purchasableItem8Price = 20;
}

void itemEnergyPotion()
{
    purchasableItem9Name = "Energy Potion";
    itemEnergyPotionDescription = "A potion that heals 10 points of health and mana.";
    purchasableItem9Price = 45;
}

void itemStatusPotion()
{
    purchasableItem10Name = "Status Potion";
    itemStatusPotionDescription = "A potion that removes all bad status effects.";
    purchasableItem10Price = 120;
}

void itemIceSword()
{
    purchasableItem11Name = "Ice Sword";
    itemIceSwordDescription = "A sword made of ice. Has a 40% chance to freeze enemies for 2 seconds.";
    purchasableItem11Price = 150;
}

void itemBomb()
{
    purchasableItem12Name = "Bomb";
    itemBombDescription = "A bomb. Blows stuff up.";
    purchasableItem12Price = 30;

}

void itemToyPlane()
{
    purchasableItem13Name = "Toy Plane";
    itemToyPlaneDescription = "A toy plane. Does absolutely nothing.";
    purchasableItem13Price = 50;
}
void shopItemDatabase()
{
    itemHeartCanister();
    itemWoodenSword();
    itemLeatherBoots();
    itemGarnetNecklace();
    itemSpookyMemeStaff();
    itemLeatherHelmet();
    itemEnergyPotion();
    itemStatusPotion(); 
    itemIceSword();
    itemBomb();
    itemToyPlane();
}
```

This is the rest of the code for the buy menu:

```
void item1()
{
    if(!isItem1Randomized)
    {
        shopItem1 = rand()%4+1;
        isItem1Randomized = true;
    }
    if(shopItem1 == 1)
    {
        shopItem1Name = purchasableItem1Name;
        shopItem1Description = itemHealthUpDescription;
        shopItem1Price = purchasableItem1Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem1 == 2)
    {
        shopItem1Name = purchasableItem2Name;
        shopItem1Description = itemWoodenSwordDescription;
        shopItem1Price = purchasableItem2Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem1 == 3)
    {
        shopItem1Name = purchasableItem3Name;
        shopItem1Description = itemLeatherBootsDescription;
        shopItem1Price = purchasableItem3Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem1 == 4)
    {
        shopItem1Name = purchasableItem4Name;
        shopItem1Description = itemGarnetNecklaceDescription;
        shopItem1Price = purchasableItem4Price;
    }
}
void item2()
{
    if(!isItem2Randomized)
    {
        shopItem2 = rand()%4+1;
        isItem2Randomized = true;
        cout << shopItem2;
    }
    if(shopItem2 == 1)
    {
        shopItem2Name = purchasableItem5Name;
        shopItem2Description = itemSpookyMemeStaffDescription;
        shopItem2Price = purchasableItem5Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem2 == 2)
    {
        shopItem2Name = purchasableItem6Name;
        shopItem2Description = itemLeatherHelmetDescription;
        shopItem2Price = purchasableItem6Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem2 == 3)
    {
        shopItem2Name = purchasableItem7Name;
        shopItem2Description = itemHealthPotionDescription;
        shopItem2Price = purchasableItem7Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem2 == 4)
    {
        shopItem2Name = purchasableItem8Name;
        shopItem2Description = itemManaPotionDescripton;
        shopItem2Price = purchasableItem8Price;
    }
}
void item3()
{
    if(!isItem3Randomized)
    {
        shopItem3 = rand()%4+1;
        isItem3Randomized = true;
    }
    if(shopItem3 == 1)
    {
        shopItem3Name = purchasableItem9Name;
        shopItem3Description = itemHealthUpDescription;
        shopItem3Price = purchasableItem9Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem3 == 2)
    {
        shopItem3Name = purchasableItem10Name;
        shopItem3Description = itemWoodenSwordDescription;
        shopItem3Price = purchasableItem10Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem3 == 3)
    {
        shopItem3Name = purchasableItem11Name;
        shopItem3Description = itemLeatherBootsDescription;
        shopItem3Price = purchasableItem11Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem3 == 4)
    {
        shopItem3Name = purchasableItem12Name;
        shopItem3Description = itemGarnetNecklaceDescription;
        shopItem3Price = purchasableItem12Price;
    }
}
void item4()
{
    if(!isItem4Randomized)
    {
        shopItem4 = rand()%4+1;
        isItem4Randomized = true;
    }
    if(shopItem4 == 1)
    {
        shopItem4Name = purchasableItem13Name;
        shopItem4Description = itemHealthUpDescription;
        shopItem4Price = purchasableItem13Price;

    }
    else if(shopItem4 == 2)
    {
        shopItem4Name = purchasableItem14Name;
        shopItem4Description = itemWoodenSwordDescription;
        shopItem4Price = purchasableItem14Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem4 == 3)
    {
        shopItem4Name = purchasableItem15Name;
        shopItem4Description = itemLeatherBootsDescription;
        shopItem4Price = purchasableItem15Price;
    }
    else if(shopItem4 == 4)
    {
        shopItem4Name = purchasableItem16Name;
        shopItem4Description = itemGarnetNecklaceDescription;
        shopItem4Price = purchasableItem16Price;
    }
}

void itemSelector()
{
    item1();
    item2();
    item3();
    item4();
}
void buyMenu()
{
    if(mazeActive == 2)
    {
        if((shop1[17][17] == shop1[playerY][playerX]))
        {
            isEnteredShop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isEnteredShop = false;
        }
    }
    if(isEnteredShop)
    {
        itemSelector();
        cout << "You have entered the shop. Items to buy: \n";

        if(!isItem1Bought)
        {
            cout << "1. " << shopItem1Name << ":\n"
                 << shopItem1Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem1Price << "\n \n";
        }
        if(!isItem2Bought)
        {
            cout << "2. " << shopItem3Name << ":\n"
                 << shopItem3Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem3Price << "\n \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Something broke";
        }
        if(!isItem3Bought)
        {
            cout << "3. " << shopItem2Name << ":\n"
                 << shopItem2Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem2Price << "\n \n";
        }
        if(!isItem4Bought)
        {
            cout << "4. " << shopItem4Name << ":\n"
                 << shopItem4Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem4Price << "\n \n";
        }

        cout << "5. Exit shop. \n";

        cin >> shop1ItemBought;
        if((shop1ItemBought == 1) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem1Name))
        {
            playerHealthPoints = playerHealthPoints + itemHeartCanisterPlayerStatisticChanges;
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - purchasableItem1Price;
            isItem1Bought = true;
            isMoved = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 1) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem2Name))
        {
            playerDamage++;
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - purchasableItem2Price;
            isItem1Bought = true;
            isMoved = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 1) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem3Name))
        {
            speedStatistic++;
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - purchasableItem3Price;
            isItem1Bought = true;
            isMoved = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 1) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem4Name))
        {
            playerDamage++;
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - purchasableItem4Price;
            isItem1Bought = true;
            isMoved = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 2) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem5Name))
        {
            playerCurrency =- purchasableItem5Price;
            hasSpookyMemeStaff = true;
            isItem2Bought = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 2) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem6Name))
        {
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - shopItem2Price;
            playerDefense+=2;
            isItem2Bought = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 2) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem7Name))
        {
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - shopItem2Price;
            playerHealthPoints++;
            isItem2Bought = true;
        }
        else if((shop1ItemBought == 2) && (shopItem1Name == purchasableItem8Name))
        {
            playerCurrency = playerCurrency - shopItem2Price;
            playerMana+=10;
            isItem2Bought = true;
        }
        isEnteredShop = false;
    }
}
```

Everything in this code works, other than the one section in the shop. It prints all of the items in the shop other than the third item. I can switch the items around and wherever those certain items are, they dont print. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you post a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal), maybe someone will bother to  debug your code.

Comment: Looks like a copy-and-paste bug. Consider using vectors (or even arrays) of Items, and loops.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using structures and containers.  Many of your functions can be eliminated by using a `std::vector` of a structure.

Answer (score 3):

Your programming style involves a lot of code duplication, this invites errors. @AJNeufeld already showed you how you mixed up certain variable names. In cases where you have numbers in your variable names, and those numbers can be larger than 2, it is very likely you should have been using arrays instead.
Another issue is that you have `shopItemXName`, `shopItemXDescription` and so on, or put otherwise, lots of properties of shop items. It is best to group such things into a struct. Then you can do something like this:

```
struct ShopItem {
    char *name;
    char *description;
    int price;
    bool bought;
};

const int nItems = 4;
struct ShopItem shopItems[nItems];
```

Later on you can then refactor a lot of repetetive code into for-loops, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
    if (!shopItems[i].bought) {
        cout << i << ". " << shopItems[i].name << ":\n"
             << shopItems[i].description << "\n"
             << "$" << shopItems[i].price << "\n \n";
    }
}
```

This will obviously also save you a lot of typing, and makes it easier to change things later, like making it so your shop sells 5 items.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to step back from the keyboard. Take a deep breath. Count backward by 7s from 1000 to 200.

Now think hard about what you're doing here. Quite a bit of the code you have here is really just data. It would be much better (at least in my opinion) if you represented that data as actual data.

Let's start with your list of items. Each item seems to have three elements: a name, a description, and a price. So, let's define a structure for that:

```
struct item { 
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    int price;
};
```

With that, we can define our table of items something like this:

```
std::vector<item> database { 
    { "Heart Canister", "Increases your maximum health by 1.", 25 },
    { "Wooden Sword", "Increases your damage by 2.", 40 },
    /* ... */
    { "Toy Plane", "A toy plane. Does absolutely nothing.", 50 }
};
```

Now, at least as I understand things, what you want to do is choose 4 items to display--one from the first four in the database, the next from the second 4, and so on.

Let's start by writing a little function to generate a number in a range. For the moment, we're going to just make it as simple as possible, not really the best possible way of doing things:

```
int rand_range(int lower, int upper) { 
    int range = upper - lower;

    return rand() % range + lower;
}
```

Since our items are in a vector, we can just choose four items by number:

```
std::vector<size_t> chosen_items;

for (int i=0; i<16; i+= 4)
    chosen_items.push_back(rand_range(i, i+4));
```

Then we have to be able to display those items. Let's start with a little function to display *one* item:

```
void display(item const &i) {
    std::cout << i.name << "\t" i.description << "\t" << i.price << "\n";
}
```

Then we can display our items something like this:

```
for (int i : chosen_items)
    display(database[i]);
```

This is still open to a lot of further improvement--but I think the general route is likely to produce a much more satisfactory result than the direction your code was going.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick glance, it looks like you've mixed up your 2's and 3's.

```
    if(!isItem2Bought)
    {
        cout << "2. " << shopItem3Name << ":\n"
             << shopItem3Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem3Price << "\n \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Something broke";
    }
    if(!isItem3Bought)
    {
        cout << "3. " << shopItem2Name << ":\n"
             << shopItem2Description << "\n" << "$" << shopItem2Price << "\n \n";
    }
```

You probably want to keep `isItem2Bought` with `shopItem2Name`, not `shopItem3Name`, etc.